# Android 7 won't update

Tags: updates

On my Alcatel U5 I keep getting a massage saying that a system update has been downloaded, press instal. When I do that it fails saying the file is corrupt and it will download again, same thing happens over and over again.

So, two questions:

1. What is the latest Android version available for my U5?
2. How can I get the download and install to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that version 7 was officially supported on this device , only Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) , according to gsm-arena at least.

I do have one of these a 5044Y myself although I have broken it by accidental removal of the proinfo and preloader, despite putting them back it's dead.

Back to your update question don't use the inbuilt  phone updater try the PC Suite instead from Alcatel, this is different software to the regular " manage your photos and stuff " one.

Look here and if the newest one does not work try an older version:

https://www.alcatelmobile.com/support/software-drivers/

You may find this could well update it.